# Method Undefined for the Type in Android

Tags: java, android

I have an error stating something like:

> The method foo() is undefined for the type bar(){}

Eclipse tells me that after entering this code:

```
((application_variables) this.getApplication()).setSomeVariable("foo");
```

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but I have it located under....

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
```

I'm guessing it has a problem with "this." 
I'm still learning about Android so I'm going pretty basic. What do I need to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah,  if you are using an inner anonymous class, the problem could the `this`. Try this:

```
((application_variables) YourActivity.this.getApplication()).setSomeVariable("foo");
```